# Spring Configuration Settings For Neo4j

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nosql, neo4j

I would like to integrate the "neo4j_config.props" file from
http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Configuration_Settings#Optimizing_for_traversals_example

into the :
[a neo4j spring app](http://news.neo4j.org/2009/02/first-complete-neo4j-sample-app.html), the graphDbService which is configured the in app-config.xml:

```
<bean id="graphDbService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"
    init-method="enableRemoteShell" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/home/neo/var/neo4j-db"/>
</bean>
```

more info: Optimizing neo4j for traversal in Spring
http://www.mail-archive.com/user@lists.neo4j.org/msg04270.html

What would be the best way to do this?  Using a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer  or using using spring-util (PropertiesFactoryBean)Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered @ [Populating a spring bean using a constructor-arg field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466437/populating-a-spring-bean-using-a-constructor-arg-field)