# Injecting java.util.Random on a constructor

Tags: java, spring, code-injection

I have a class HiddenNumber with this constructor:

```
public HiddenNumber(java.util.Random random, int maxNumberOfDigits) {
  /* some code */
}
```

I´m trying to use annotations for DI as:

```
@Autowired
public HiddenNumber(@Value("T(java.util.Random") random, 
    @Value("4")int maxNumberOfDigits) {
  /* some code */
}
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried:

```
@Autowired
public HiddenNumber(@Value("#{T(java.util.Random}") random, 
    @Value("4")int maxNumberOfDigits) {
  /* some code */
}
```

If I do:

```
@Autowired
public HiddenNumber(Random random, @Value("4") int maxNumberOfDigits) {
  /* some code */
}
```

And in the app-context.xml do:

```
<bean class="java.util.Random" />
```

It works ok. But of course I prefer to do only annotations.

What is the correct way to inject java.util.Random?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't inject something you don't have a bean for. If you prefer annotations, just create a java based configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@Autowired
public HiddenNumber(@Value("#{new java.util.Random()}") Random random, @Value("4")int maxNumberOfDigits) {
...
}
```

Comment: Is the `@Autowired` still required?

Comment: Yes, the assumption is that there is a stereotype annotation on the HiddenNumber Bean:`@Service public class HiddenNumber {`

Comment: I don't understand what `@Service` has to do with `@Autowired` in this situation.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, `@Service` is not required. I was assuming that the bean is being instantiated with a Stereotype annotation. It need not be, it can be instantiated with a normal xml bean definition also.

Comment: If you're newing it with an expression in the constructor, what is the rationale for injecting it in the first place, if it's not being configured somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Spring's `<constructor-arg>` element. See for example [Populating a spring bean using a constructor-arg field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466437/populating-a-spring-bean-using-a-constructor-arg-field) or [this here](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-bean-constructor-injection-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for a very simple program, and I solved using SpEL.

In order to use the p: prefix you must include this property in beans tag:
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"