# Spring Annotations: How to create autowire annotation for static/non static method with arguments

Tags: java, spring, annotations

1. Using annotations; how do i pass arguments values to a method ? 
   Example in the below code "How can i pass arguments (2 strings) values for loadProperties API method" through annotations when Autowiring of confProps instance?
2. I can use @javax.inject.Named at method argument level; but is there any equivalent for this in Spring to use at method argument level? I am not able to use @Component at the argument level.
3. Can i use these @Value("#{XXX}")  OR @Qualifier("") to resolve my issue? These two are supported at method argument level.

Also please correct me if any other configuration mistakes i did it here.

```
@Configuration
Class Utilities {

    @Bean(name = "loadProperties")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public static Properties loadProperties(String propsFileName, String type) throws Exception {
        return Utilities.loadPropertiesFile(p_propsFileName);
    }

}


@Service
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
@Qualifier("strmContMgr")
public class StreamingControllerManager {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("loadProperties")
    Properties confProps;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use static with spring for Autowire

Comment: @SRT_KP http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method

Comment: @SRT_KP If you are saying the problem is because of static; Could you please give some examples for non static method

Answer (score 1):

Like any technology, Spring has it's taunts and limits. From your example, you have started to try to do everything (even the most simple things) using Spring. Looking at how you got there, that might make sense but you still ended up in a corner.

Or to put it another way: Just because you **can** doesn't mean it's **smart** to do.

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
@Configuration
Class StreamContollerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Properties streamControllerProperties() throws Exception {
        return Utilities.loadPropertiesFile("some/fixed/name");
    }
}
```

Try to avoid runtime "configurable" beans. They add a lot of complexity to your product with often little benefit.

Build your application from blocks with one final "configuration" block that wires and weaves everything together. That way, each block stays independent and simple.

Comment: Thank you!! but i dont want to hard code "some/fixed/name"; It should read from property file; OR beans.xml; Could you pls help on that!!

Comment: I understand that you really try hard to make your project a failure. I can only suggest not to do it. Only pain awaits you along this path.

Comment: You do realize that you can have dozens of `@Configuration` beans and that you can easily switch between them? At the end, you will have one master bean which will pull in all the other configurations that you want.

Comment: +1 OK I am not able to understand much but anyhow; Thanks a lot for your support!! Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how this can be done through Annotation. For time being I am following XML way.

```
public class Utilities {
    public static Properties loadProperties(String propsFileName, String type) throws Exception {
        return Utilities.loadPropertiesFile(p_propsFileName);
    }
}


@Service
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
@Qualifier("strmContMgr")
public class StreamingControllerManager {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("loadProperties")
    Properties confProps;
}

<beans>
    <bean id="loadProperties" class="com.pactolus.Utilities" 
      factory-method="loadPropertiesFile">
      <constructor-arg index="0" value="sc_beans.xml"/>
      <constructor-arg index="1" value="CC"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```